# C using getOpt to parse multiple arguments

Tags: c, parsing, getopt

I need to use getopt to parse the following command:

```
./center -n name –cp Anumber –i Anumber –t Anumber –s Anumber -fc nameOfaFile
```

All of them can be given out in any order.

So its clear i have to use getOpt.

So i have been investigation and this is what i have so far

```
 void check_parameters (int argc, char** argv) {
    int opt; 

    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:cp:i:c:fc:")) != -1) {
       printf("give me opt %c \n", opt)
       swicth(opt){
          case 'n' :
             //do something
          case 'cp' :
             //do something
          case 'i' :
            //do something
       }
    }
  }
```

I do know for a fact that the 3 parameter: the OptString is where i tell getOpt what are the char of the options it should expect
Also in optarg is where the argument is

its not working!
when i printf( "give me opt %c", opt ) its giving me the numbers, not the char!

for this reason it does not work. it does not check the parameters correctly

Edit:
After doing man 3 getopt
the return value of getopt is:  If an option was successfully found, then getopt() returns  the  option character.  If all command-line options have been parsed, then getopt() returns -1.
it returns the option character? it always return integer 1. always! i don't understand how getopt works. how does the switch compare to characters?!

Comment: getopt handles single character options, it can't handle e.g. `fc` as a single option. Also case 'cp' is wrong, you can't specify 2 characters as a single character litteral. And please show the real code you have including where you print out the option - the current code makes very little sense, and show us the actual output of your program.

Comment: Do "man getopt"; it does return an int. I do not get your question.

Comment: Would you mind posting actual compilable code? This code is full of non-sense and syntax errors.

Comment: @hari  If an option was successfully found, then getopt() returns  the  option character. If all command-line options have been parsed, then getopt() returns -1.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this:

```
case 'cp':
```

...makes no sense. You can't represent two characters with a `char` or `int`. Besides, if running your program with `-cp 101`, getopt will treat it as `-c p 101`, for a completely different result. If you want to use long options, use `getopt_long` instead and the appropriate calling syntax, per example: `./a.out -n 42 --cp 101`.

Now, here's a working example of `getopt()` in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int opt;

  while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:cp:i:c:fc:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt){
      case 'n':
        printf("n was %s\n", optarg);
        break;

      case 'i':
        printf("i was %s\n", optarg);
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alessandroempire: Are you passing switches to your executable?

Comment: no i havent.. which is strange. something simple is not working.

Comment: actually it makes no sense what is written there: opt is an interger, when 'n is a char. how the hell are you going to compare integer with char?

Comment: @Alessandroempire: Both `char` and `int` have integer types, but they are probably of different size. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

`getopt` handles only single-character option names, not things like `-cp` or `-fc` (which it interprets as multiple option flags in a single string: `-c -p`, `-f -c`). If you want to stick to the syntax you defined, then it's easier to just roll your own:

```
// first check whether argc is odd, then:
for (i = 1; i < argc; i += 2) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "n") == 0) {
        name = argv[i+1];
    } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "cp") == 0) {
        // etc. etc.
    }
}
```